# Content-Security-Policy and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I have a trouble with settings Content-Security-Policy

I have .html file, external .css and external .js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Without Content-Security-Policy page works...

If I set:

> Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; child-src
> 'self'; connect-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; base-uri 'self';
> style-src 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; upgrade-insecure-requests;
> frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; media-src
> 'self'; frame-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self';"

There is a problem with JavaScript. It does not work.

If I paste .js into .html file (internal script), in CPS I rewrite script-src 'unsafe-inline' - my page works... (As without CPS settings). But it is unsafe...

How can I do external working .js with safetly settings in CPS? This is a horror for me. Thank you very much.

Page is same as this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox

Answer (score 1):

### Your example has unsafe-inline JS (and CSS)!

Your click handlers on the images are inline JS.

**`onclick="currentSlide(1)"`**

You need to move those to a handler inside your external JS file.

Additionally you have the same problem with your CSS, the inline styles will get blocked

**`style="width:100%"`**

In the below example I have moved your click handler to the external JS file and moved your inline CSS into the external file.

If you ran the below example on your server you would find that the first image is both smaller and does not respond to a click event (as inline JS and CSS is blocked) and the other two images are the same size (as CSS via a class in external file sets the width correctly) and both respond to click events (as your JS is not inline anymore).

```js
var clickHandler = function(e){
    console.log(e.target.src);
}

var images = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  
  images[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
}
```

```css
.container{
 width: 25%;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.demo{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<!--original image has inline JavaScript with "onclick" and inline CSS with "style=", netiehr of these will work with your CSP-->
<img class="demo cursor" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">

<!--moved the click handler into the external file using "addEventListener" and moved the inline CSS to the external CSS file - this will work with your CSP-->
<img class="demo cursor" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Nature and sunrise">
<img class="demo cursor" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" alt="Nature and sunrise">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a better example... http://kod.djpw.cz/dmxc

With no Content-Security-Policy this works...

I want to have this:

Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; child-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; style-src 'self'; block-all-mixed-content; upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self';"

I understand to remove `style="width:100%"` in images...

I want to make `onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)"` that will open 2th image (or `onclick="currentSlide(2)"`) and make close `onclick="closeModal()"`

This is what I dont want how to do...

(In example click "Uložit a získat odkaz"), than you will have own link with update)

Comment: Your question was about CSP. The answer I gave you explained what to do to fix your CSP blocking your JS, if you want help changing your code to change functionality then you should ask a different question for that. I showed you an example of how to create a click handler that resides in an external file, which lets you remove the click handler. If you want to put a fiddle together of what i told you to do I can help you correct any errors with it but this is a completely different thing you are asking for.